# Javascript & Jquery for fixed navigation bar stops working when online (web-server)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-hosting

Thanks for looking at my question!

I'm very inexperienced with HTML and flat-out bad with JavaScript or jQuery. Couldn't find a solution to my problem anywhere.

The problem is that I have a website with a fixed navigation bar using a javascript and Jquery. Everything works when I open my html on my local machine but when I upload my website online the code stops working.

I don't know if this is enough information for anyone to get an idea of what the problem is but I figured it has to do with something I don't understand in the head, since the script and paths work fine when offline / local. (All the folders and files are in the same order and directories in my web-server)

https://thorned.xyz/ maybe the online website could help. 
The menu bar is not fixed when you scroll on a small page unlike when I open the html offline.

Thanks in advance!

```html
<head>
  <link 
   rel="icon" 
   type="image/png" 
   href="favicon.png">
  <title>Thorned.xyz - Resources for everyone</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   
<!---Link to menu html--->
  <div class="menutop">
   <object class="menu" type="text/html" data="menu.html"></object>
  </div>
<!----Link to script--->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/scrollfix.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        // top bar
        $('.menutop').scrollFix({
            side: 'top'
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the jquery cdn is served over http where as your website is as https causing an insecure script error. Change your http to https on the jquery plugin `(https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax...)`